# Java speech recognition API using the result listener

Tags: nullpointerexception, speech, jsapi

I am quite new to java programming and have been teaching myself through reading online and buying a few java programming books here and there.

However I am running into a problem when building a speech recognition program I have been working on for a few weeks now. It is giving me a `nullpointer exception at the rec.addresultlistener` coding line and I have absoloutely no idea why, because to my knowledge that line is there to tell the program to listen for a input in order to check it against the grammar. This program was previously giving me the same errors for the  `rec.allocate()` coding line but that was fixed by declaring it null. Am I supposed to declare this as null as well?

Can someone please help me out here and also explain why?

```
    //Create a recognizer that supports English
        rec = Central.createRecognizer( new EngineModeDesc (Locale.ENGLISH));;

        //Start up the recognizer
        if(rec!=null){
        rec.allocate();


    //Load the grammar from a file, and enable it
        System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsoluteFile());
                    FileReader reader = new FileReader("grammar2.0");
                if (reader != null) System.out.println("no file");;
        System.out.println(reader);
        RuleGrammar gram = rec.loadJSGF(reader);
        gram.setEnabled(true);
        }
        //Add the listener to get results

     rec.addResultListener(new speech());


        //commit the grammar
        rec.commitChanges();

        //Request focus and start listening
        rec.requestFocus();
        rec.resume();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It is a good idea to provide details on which exact API implementation you are using. Also when you report exceptions it is a good idea to provide the stacktrace. The more complete information you provide the faster you get an answer.